# Translate ECMAScript 6's arrow function to a regular function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to convert the script below to a normal function, but fail to understand how.

The script counts the numbers of instances (model) in a Array (productList.Lockers) and appends it to a target div.

```
productList.Lockers.forEach(o => $('#' + o.model).siblings('#modelcount').text((i, t) => (  parseInt(t, 10) || 0) + 1 ));
var modelCount = document.getElementById('allcount');
modelCount.innerHTML = productList.Lockers.length;
```

Comment: are you converting the arrow functions into normal functions or the whole script (which wouldn't make sense)? is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems easy:

```
productList.Lockers.forEach(function(o) {
  return $('#' + o.model).siblings('#modelcount').text(function(i, t) {
    return (parseInt(t, 10) || 0) + 1
  })
})
```